# Dell U2715H black screen on an HP ZBook Studio G4 running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, video, hdmi

Just got an external monitor delivered. Plugged it in the first time and it worked, but was trying to sort out some resolution quirks between the external and internal displays. Rebooted and the monitor no longer worked and goes directly to power save mode or simply isn't detected at all depending on the cable used. Seems a few people have run into similar problems, but the solutions that I've found so far haven't worked for me. Hoping someone can shed some light on this. TIA.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

`xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  50.00    48.02  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

`lshw -c video`

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM107GLM [Quadro M1200 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:133 memory:e3000000-e3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Well, `xrandr` is listing it means it is detected and connected, so maybe the resolution or refresh rate or some configuration is invalid, so the display is ignoring the invalid video signal. Maybe try to install `arandr` and run it to change the resolution down again and see if that brings the video signal back.

Comment: @darksky That seems to be the laptop display. The external monitor isn't detected. I grabbed a new DP cable and initially it worked and I was able to get resolutions configured and work on it, but after a reboot the same thing happened: Nothing but power save mode on the external monitor.